# Ubuntu 16.04: Not opening in dual boot with windows 8.1

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi, windows-8

I was using windows 8.1 in dual boot with Ubuntu 16.04 for over 4 months or so. I usually booted to Ubuntu where I got those four options to start ubuntu, advanced boot options, start windows, etc. One fine day, my laptop booted to windows 8.1 by default. To look into the matter, I rebooted the laptop and paused the startup and pressed F9 key to view all boot device options.

According to the device priority order, ubuntu still was at the higher level of priority than windows, still, I chose to boot **ubuntu**. Next thing which I was seeing was my laptop booting to windows. No grub menu and nothing.

I saw various similar questions on StackExchange sites but none of the solutions seemed to be working for me. Any insight on how to go about resolving this?

Answer (score 1):

Something very similar happened to me about 6 months ago while I was using 15.02. Grub for me seemed to stop working completely and starting always just booting into windows. Which was quite annoying, because I mainly work in ubuntu. So I found this cool tool (Link to where I found it: http://www.howtogeek.com/114884/how-to-repair-grub2-when-ubuntu-wont-boot/). Which is a boot-repair, which will give you some options on automatic fixes and grub re-installs.

Another thing I would try if your grub menu isn't appearing is to see if holding SHIFT down while you are booting will bring up grub. If it still doesn't show up, then maybe in some update your grub timeout somehow switched to 0. Try locating the /etc/default/grub file and editing it (root needed). Then change what ever value that's in there like this:

```
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=X
GRUB_TIMEOUT=X
GRUB_DEFAULT=X
```

Replace the X's with these values (Or whatever you want)

```
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=3
GRUB_TIMEOUT=15
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
```

Save and exit the file and run

```
sudo update-grub
```

If after all of that it doesn't work, I looked around google some more and maybe it's not all Ubuntu's fault... Here is a link to something that looks like windows UEFI hogging all of the fun. http://www.linuxubuntu.org/fix-grub-not-showing-for-windows-10-linux-dual-boot/

Answer (score 0):

My /home folder is always kept in a separate partition.  This way I can reinstall Ubuntu from a flash drive when I have problems.  (Just don't format /home.)

I find that when I have boot problems or other OS related problems that 9/10 of the time reinstalling Ubuntu fixes it.

If your /home is in a separate partition, you can reinstall Ubuntu by choosing "other" and selecting each of the existing partitions for Ubuntu and checking "format" to all but /home.